# VB.Net Object sort by 2 propreties

Tags: vb.net, sorting, object

I have an Object with 3 properties (width, height, and quantity), and I have it sorting by height with:

```
pA.Sort(Function(x, y) y.height.CompareTo(x.height))
```

How can I then sort by width if there are matching heights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pA.Sort(Function(x, y) Iif(y.height.CompareTo(x.height) = 0, y.width.CompareTo(x.width), y.height.CompareTo(x.height)))
```

You can try using multi-line lambda to prevent `t.height.CompareTo(x.height)` being executed twice:

```
pA.Sort(Function(x, y)
            Dim heightDifference = y.height.CompareTo(x.height)
            If Not heightDifference = 0 Then
                Return heightDifference
            Else
                Return y.width.CompareTo(x.width)
            End If
        End Function)
```

or you can use LINQ, but it will recreate the list sorted instead of sorting it in place

```
pA = pA.OrderBy(Function(x) x.height).ThenBy(Function(x) x.width).ToList()
```